# Convert String Timestamp to timestamp in PHP

Tags: php, date, timestamp

I have a string like "1427835599999" that I want to convert to timestamp so I can use it in the date() function.

So far I have tried these:

```
$time = date("Y-m-d", $timestamp);
```

which returns an error ($timestamp is expected to be a long, string given);

```
$time = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($timestamp));
```

which returns 01-01-1970

So I need to convert my string to long so I can use it in the date function.

Thanks

EDIT:

(int)$timestamp is not working either. $timestamp+0 is not working.

Comment: `1427835599999` is not a valid timestamp (= 04/22/47216 @ 11:59pm (UTC))

Comment: I tested here and it was the date I desired... http://www.epochconverter.com/

Comment: The date you want is 04/22/47216? I find that hard to believe.

Comment: Depending on your OS (32 vs 64 bit), this may or may not throw an error. When I do it, it works just fine (no error) and prints 47216-04-22 for the date. I expect that on a 32 bit system, you will fail because the timestamp is too large.

Comment: Did you check my link? the date I want is 31 of March 2015

Comment: It's milliseconds since unix timestamp base date, not seconds: `$timestamp = "1427835599999";
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", floor($timestamp / 1000)), PHP_EOL;` gives `2015-03-31 20:59:59` UTC

Comment: Thank you! that was the problem. The date was in milliseconds. Thanks a bunch Mark!

Comment: If you look at the manual, `date()` clearly states that the timestamp must in seconds.

Comment: I know that. I had a Javascript function that was not doing its job correctly. Anyway, thank you

Comment: Epoch Converter does specifically say `Assuming that this timestamp is in milliseconds:`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks as a product of javascript's `.getTime()` function, returning number of milliseconds since 1970/01/01, hence 13 digits as opposed to timestamp being the number of seconds, so having 10 digits. Just divide it by 1000:

```
$time = date("Y-m-d", $timestamp/1000);
echo $time; // output: 2015-03-31
```

Comment: Thank you very much. For giving the right answer and for not being harsh :)